# Got different answer from a return of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml2js

I'm blocked since few hours now, I wish somebody can help me figure out what I do wrong.
This whole code is to get a json response from an API. I want to understand what are my errors, so please, explain a little ! ;)

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');
fetch.Promise = Bluebird;
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

module.exports = {

    getImage : async function (tag, random){
        
        let url = "anApiLink" + tag;

        if(random != null) url = "anApiLink" + tag + "&id=" + random;
        
        const get_data = async url => {
            
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                
                if(! response.ok) return new Error("Erreur lors de la récupération de l'image : " + response.statusText);
                
                const text = await response.text();



                const xmlToJson = await xml2js.parseString(text, (err, result) => {
                    
                    if(err) throw err;

                    const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);  

                    return json;
                });
                
                console.log(xmlToJson);
                return xmlToJson;

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        };

        return get_data(url);
            
    }
}
```

My json const is what I want to return from the global function (get_data), and it's an actual good json answer. With my final return, I actually get what's below.

From my `console.log()` :

```
{
  comment: '',
  sgmlDecl: '',
  textNode: '',
  tagName: '',
  doctype: '',
  procInstName: '',
  procInstBody: '',
  entity: '',
  attribName: '',
  attribValue: '',
  cdata: '',
  script: '',
  c: '',
  q: '',
  bufferCheckPosition: 65536,
  opt: { trim: false, normalize: false, xmlns: false, lowercase: undefined },
  looseCase: 'toUpperCase',
  tags: [],
  sawRoot: false,
  closedRoot: false,
  closed: false,
  error: null,
  tag: null,
  strict: true,
  noscript: true,
  state: 0,
  strictEntities: undefined,
  ENTITIES: {},
  attribList: [],
  trackPosition: true,
  column: 0,
  line: 0,
  position: 0,
  errThrown: false,
  onerror: [Function],
  onend: [Function],
  ended: true,
  onopentag: [Function],
  onclosetag: [Function],
  ontext: [Function],
  oncdata: [Function],
  startTagPosition: 781
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salut, I didn't even realize at first that I was reading french in your code... Your problem seemed to be related to that library you're using, `xml2js`. I took a look at their docs, and maybe [this may help you](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#promise-usage).

The function itself does not return the result, but you can get it in the callback, that's the reason why you're logging this weird object. You could create a separate var to store the result, but I have a better solution.

If you want to use promises, I found [this](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#promise-usage) in the docs, and [this](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/master/src/parser.coffee#L259-L265) in the source code about `parseStringPromise`, and I think that's what you want. The source code indicates that the result is returned as a Promise here.

In short, what you return in the callback isn't returned by `parseString`. This is what `xmlToJson` should be to act as intended.

```js
// Not tested. I might have made an error about the location of 'then', not sure.
const xmlToJson = await xml2js.parseStringPromise(text)
  .catch(e => throw e)
  .then(r => JSON.stringify(r, null, 4))
```